# how to step over and step return when using bochs to debug

Tags: debugging, assembly, bochs

For example, now I am debugging to the line:

```
[0x000000000009048a] 0008:0009048a (unk. ctxt): call .-225 (0x000903ae)   ; e81fffffff
```

I don't want to step into the function. That's to say, I want to step over and go to address: 0008:0009048f directly. Can bochs do that? And if I have stepped into function, how can I step to return directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, bochs supports stepping over subroutine calls:

```
n|next|p - execute instruction stepping over subroutines
```

No, bochs doesn't support running to exit of frame. You can work around this limitation by setting a breakpoint (tedious for recursive functions, though).